# How can I force compiler to use default constructor when adding element to vector using emplace_back?

Tags: c++, c++11

How can I force compiler to use default constructor when adding element to vector using emplace_back?

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

enum E {E1, E2};

struct A
{
  A(){}
  A(int i){}
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<std::pair<E, A>> testMap;

  testMap.emplace_back(E1, 10);
  // testMap.emplace_back(E2);
}
```

Commented out line gives following error:
error C2664: 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>::pair(const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'E' to 'const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just like you can't construct a `std::pair<E, A>` from just `E1`, you can't emplace it either. So just provide a default-constructed `A`:

```
testMap.emplace_back(E1, A{});
```

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer does call `A`'s default constructor.  But it also calls `A`'s compiler-supplied move constructor.  If you would like to call *only* `A`'s default constructor, you can do this:

```
testMap.emplace_back(std::piecewise_construct, std::forward_as_tuple(E1),
                                               std::forward_as_tuple());
```

Or here is a minor re-spelling:

```
testMap.emplace_back(std::piecewise_construct, std::forward_as_tuple(E1),
                                               std::tuple<>{});
```

These rewrites are admittedly much uglier than:

```
testMap.emplace_back(E1, A{});
```

But if saving a call to `A(A&&)` is something you want to do, this is how to do it.